# Objective c UIPageViewController remove shadow when flipping

Tags: objective-c, shadow, uipageviewcontroller, page-flipping

Just a quick question, is it possible to remove the shadow of UIPageviewcontroller when flipping ? Ex: [example of shadow](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Image%3aIphone_ios_5_uipageviewcontroller_app.jpg)

Thanks,

Comment: I really don't think this'll work, but have you tried just nilling out the page controller's view's layer's shadow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

99% certain you won't be able to accomplish this with a one-liner. Your best bet is to find code where someone reimplemented the page-turn animation themselves and remove the code which draws the shadow from that.